# How to create a Range from a specific cell to variable one

Tags: excel, vba

I want to set a Range from "D250" to an always changing cell

But I can't put a variable to set code line! Set newRng = ws.Range("D250:endRngMun") endRngMun is always changing...

```
Sub Compare()

    Dim ws  As Worksheet
    Dim munCompt As Long
    Dim totalMun As Long
    Dim endRngMun As String



    Set ws = Sheets("T1")

    ' find last row with data in Column B at current regioun starting at cell B10
    With ws.Range("D250").CurrentRegion
        munCompt = .Rows(.Rows.Count).Row
    End With

    Dim Rng         As Range
    Set Rng = ws.Range("D250:D" & munCompt)

    ' find last row inside the range, ignore values inside formulas
    munCompt = Rng.Find(What:="*", _
                        After:=Range("D250"), _
                        LookAt:=xlPart, _
                        LookIn:=xlValues, _
                        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                        SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                        MatchCase:=False).Row


    totalMun = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Rng)

    endRngMun = "D" & 250 + totalMun - 1

    Dim newRng As Range
    Set newRng = ws.Range("D250:endRngMun")

    ' for debug
    Debug.Print newRng.Count




End Sub
```

Comment: `Set newRng = ws.Range("D250:" & endRngMun)`

Comment: Thanks  a lot !!!!!